# Please explain why my code caused a Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Here's the code:

```
public static int maxPathLengthHelper(int[][] paths, int x, int y){
    int maxLength = 0;
    if(x > 0 && paths[x-1][y] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x-1,y);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(y > 0 && paths[x][y-1] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x,y-1);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(x < paths.length - 1 && paths[x+1][y] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x+1,y);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(y < paths[0].length - 1 && paths[x][y+1] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x,y+1);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

In the if statements where the y value is changed, a Stack Overflow error is caused, yet there is no error in the parts where the x value is changed. I was wondering why this was; if both were wrong, I would change the whole thing, but it's just in the second and fourth if statements that Stack Overflow errors are caused by the recursive call. The first and third if statements have no issues, and I have absolutely no idea what is different about them.

Comment: Your search is wiggling back and forth forever.

Comment: Now would be the *perfect* time to practice debugging skills, including running this code in your favorite IDE's debugger, setting break points, and thereby try to isolate and identify the error.

Comment: For example, please give a (quoting a flag) `desired behavior, a specific problem or error`. Also, add a sample input and output.

Comment: ok I fixed it thank you (edit: the code I mean, I got the answer I was trying for)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when your code moves from `0,0` to `1,0` it again checks for `0,0` as first `if` condition is satisfied

```
public static int[][] visitedNodes;

public static void main(String args[]){
  // when you call the recursive method, also initiate the visitedNodes
   visitedNodes = new int[totalX][totalY];
   for(int i = 0; i < totalX; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < totalY; i++)
        visitedNodes[i][j] = 0;
   maxPathLengthHelper(myPathList,0,0);
}

public static int maxPathLengthHelper(int[][] paths, int x, int y){
    int maxLength = 0;
    visitedNodes[x][y] = 1;
    if(x > 0 && visitedNodes[x-1][y] == 0 && paths[x-1][y] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x-1,y);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(y > 0 && visitedNodes[x][y-1] == 0  && paths[x][y-1] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x,y-1);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(x < paths.length - 1 && visitedNodes[x+1][y] == 0  && paths[x+1][y] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x+1,y);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    if(y < paths[0].length - 1 && visitedNodes[x][y+1] == 0  && paths[x][y+1] == 1){
        int currentLength = 1 + maxPathLengthHelper(paths,x,y+1);
        if(currentLength > maxLength){
            maxLength = currentLength;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: That will only prevent walking back, not walking in a loop, e.g. `0,0` → `0,1` → `1,1` → `1,0` → `0,0`

Comment: oh.. right.. I guess you need to maintain a Set of all the visited nodes

Comment: A new `int` array is already initialized to all zeroes, so the double `for` loop to assign `0` values is redundant.

Comment: oh, that was new.. Thanks @Andreas